# Alternatives to Bloom Filter

Tags: data-structures, bloom-filter

I have tried using bloom filter for performing membership tests. I wish to perform membership tests on 80 billion entries with only allowing around 100 collisions to happen i.e., only 100 entries can be given a false positive result.

I know this can be achieved by bloom filters but using the formulas of determining the number of bits required per entry and the number of hash functions given the allowed false positive rate. I figured I would end up using 270 GB of memory and 19 hash functions.

I also had a look at Cuckoo filter but its memory requirements don't match my requirements. My Requirements are as follows :

1. Use at max 6 bits per element
2. Use no more than 7-8 Hash Functions.

Could someone suggest me a probabilistic data structure other than the one's mentioned above that can help in achieving my requirements?

Comment: It seems unlikely that you'll find any data structure that will let you differentiate between 80 billion items, with a false positive rate of .00000000125, using only 60 gigabytes, even if you didn't have a restriction on the number of hash functions. I don't have the math to prove it, but it looks to me like you're pushing the bounds of what's theoretically possible.

Comment: Okay if I increase my memory or my false positive rate goes upto 1% of the items, then is bloom filter a good choice for my use case or is there any other probabilistic data structure that can be a better choice?

Answer (score 4):

The issue with the number of hash functions is not really a problem - just pick a single hash function with many bits of output and divide up the bits as if they were from separate hash functions. Your real problem here is the false positive rate tradeoff with storage space.

You have said

> I wish to perform membership tests on 80 billion entries with only
>   allowing around 100 collisions to happen i.e., only 100 entries can be
>   given a false positive result.

Entries that are in the map can, by definition, not be **false** positives. They are **true** positives.

The question then is "100 false positives taken over how many entries 
that you intend to test?" If the answer is also, oddly enough, 80 billion, then you are asking for a false positive rate of around 100/80,000,000,000 = 1/800,000,000, which is less than 2^-29.

The minimum space for any approximate membership data structure like Bloom filters or cuckoo filters is n lg 1/ε bits, where n is the number of elements in the structure, lg is the logarithm base 2, and ε is the false positive rate. In other words, you need more than 29 bits per element to achieve a false positive rate like 100 per 80 billion. 6 bits per element will get you 1.56% false positive rate **at best**. That's 1.25 billion per 80 billion, or 100 per 6400.

As far as I know there are no known practical data structures that come close to achieving this. Bloom filters don't, for instance, because they use more than lg 1/ε bits per item. Cuckoo filters don't because they use at least two additional metadata bits per item and have a bits-per-item rate that scales with lg n.

Comment: I know the memory requirements would be a lot more in my case. But, your suggestion of using a single hash function and dividing up the bits is interesting. Have you ever implemented this and found that the results were similar to the one's you would get by using separate hash functions?

Comment: Yes, I have implemented this, and it went fine. However, it won't work with low-quality hash families. This margin is too small to contain a more complete answer, but read up on vhash, universal hashing, SipHash, and things like this.